# Difference between string[] and [string]

Tags: typescript, types

Consider the following Typescript example. The first line results in an error 'type undefined[] is not assignable to type [string]'. The last two lines do compile.

```
let givesAnError: [string] = [];
let isOK: string[] = [];
let isAlsoOK: [string] = ["foo"];
```

How do you have to interprete the type definition `[string]` in Typescript?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The first (`givesAnError`) and last (`isAlsoOK`) [are tuples](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple), and the second (`isOK`) is an array.

With arrays all of your elements are of the same type:

```
let a: string[];
let b: boolean[];
let c: any[];
```

But with tuples you can have different types (and a fixed length):

```
let a: [string, boolean, number];
let b: [any, any, string];
```

So:

```
a = ["str1", true, 4]; // fine
b = [true, 3, "str"]; // fine
```

But:

```
a = [4, true, 3]; // not fine as the first element is not a string
b = [true, 3]; // not fine because b has only two elements instead of 3
```

It's important to understand the the javascript output will always use arrays, as there's no such thing as tuple in js.
But for the compilation time it is useful.

Comment: so [string] is just an array with 1 string inside it where string[] is an array of strings of n length

Comment: @JasonSebring Right

Answer (score 10):

## Straight to it

```
string[] // n-length array, must only contain strings

[string] // must be 1-length array, first element must be a string
```