# What's the difference between TypeName[] and [TypeName]?

Tags: typescript

What's the difference between the 2?

If I have:

```
interface MyType {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

what will happen if I do:

```
function(randomVar: [MyType]) {}
```

vs. doing:

```
function(randomVar: MyType[]) {}
```

I've seen people use it interchangeably, but what's the difference?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays Read the documentation, says it in there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between string\[\] and \[string\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39613923/difference-between-string-and-string)

Comment: `MyType[]` is an array but `[MyType]` is a tuple